# Exercises in Lie group theory for physics

Tags: gr.group-theory, textbook-recommendation, physics

I teach a course on (Lie) group theory for physics at the level of senior undergraduates. 
I follow basically the book by Georgi "Lie algebras in particle physics". So I teach them the groups SU(2), SU(3), and other related subjects.
 However there are too little exercises in this book, and I couldn't find enough exercises on the net.
Do you know where I can find exercises on (Lie) group theory FOR physicists?

Comment: (I edited the question in light of the fact that what most physicists call "group theory" is mainly known by mathematicians as "Lie group theory" - Since the book you're using is about Lie algebras, this seems to suggest it's the right interpretation)

Comment: @Qfwfq I guess, in that case possibly ([tag:lie-groups) - and maybe also ([tag:lie-algebras]) - might be worth adding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend H.F. Jones, ``Groups, representations and physics'', Institute of Physics Publishing, 1990: it has a good selection of exercises at the end of each chapter.

Answer (score 5):

Wu-Ki Tung's [Group Theory in Physics](https://books.google.com/books?id=O89tgpOBO04C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) has problems at the end of each chapter. Michael Aizazis published the [complete solutions](https://books.google.com/books?id=pLgXRcFYSLwC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) to these problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the H.F. Jones book "Group Theory in physics" can be another good reference.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what other people mentioned.

Probably the best physics oriented problem coll in group theory is given by **ROBERT GILL MORE-GROUP THEORY**
also I will strongly advocate for **A. ZEE-GROUP TH IN A NUTSHELL FOR PHYSICIST** each chapter has its own problem.